# Route an Http(s)URLConnection through a pre-existing Socket

Tags: java, sockets, http, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've spent a few infuriating hours poring over the javax.net and sun.net SSL implementations and the Apache HttpClient 4.3 SSL handling (which uses the javax.net facilities at its core by default) and have made frustratingly little progress. I'm attempting to tunnel traffic from an HttpsURLConnection through previously created Input/OutputStreams in order to have access to the HTTP java.net utilities while being able to send the data through my own streams. I originally figured I could hackishly route the HttpsURLConnection through a custom Socket instance with a SocketImpl that uses these Input/OutputStreams, but it appears that I would have to change the default HttpsURLConnection SSLFactory in order to achieve that, which is not viable as the application is multi-threaded. I'm open to alternate libraries and hackish fixes!

The end goal I wish to achieve: Http(s)URLRequest (or equivalent HTTP facility that supports SSL) -> My Custom Socket -> Internet

Comment: I'm using [Orchid](https://github.com/subgraph/Orchid) to create Tor tunnels and I need to make some HTTPS requests, so they have to be tunneled through Orchid's Stream class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your best option is to install your own `SSLSocketFactory` on each relevant `HttpsURLConnection` *instance.* It can create an `SSLSocket` instance that delegates to a real one but returns your streams wrapped around the delegate's streams.

If you need access to the cipher text for some reason, you could turn that upside down and supply your own `Socket` to `SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket, ...)`,

Comment: Did not realize that I was able to set an individual HttpsURLConnection instance's SSLSocketFactory! Thank you!

Comment: It seems that the underlying plain socket is created before `SSLSocketFactory#createSocket` is called.